# JSON Proxy: Perform cross-domain web service requests from a single-page HTML app as ubiquitously as possible?

Tags: json, proxy, cross-domain

I have a HTML5 page that performs geo queries against a bunch of catalog services and renders on google earth and other providers. Our main mission is to make this as light as possible and as portable as possible.

I realize that I have a bit of a problem when making calls to remote catalog web services -- that without overriding browser settings, request will fail do to same-origin policy.

My initial thought is to just use a small proxy somewhere on the same network as the client machine to perform the outgoing requests.

My main concern is I should be able to run this proxy without installing extra software on as many machines as possible -- what platform should I look at? Initially coming to mind are Java and perl.

I will need to run on Mac, Windows, and Linux boxes for sure, and potentially Solaris/sparc. I don't necessarilly need the same proxy across all platforms, but it would be ideal.

Edit: This is a fairly specific case -- could I accomplish this with e.g a chrome plugin? It really only has to work on one browser, but that browser has to run on most/all platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone searches this, I have offered my app with the following workarounds:

A small node.js Proxy: Approx 10 lines of code and I have a standalone proxy to get around CORS

A Chrome Extension: Extensions can make CORS requests.

Flash Object (Not Tried): Flash Objects can make CORS requests, or so I read

A firefox extension: Same as the chrome situation

Instructions on how to have the remote services enable CORS.

Comment: Can you show or point me to the 10 line of NodeJS proxy code you have?  I've had little luck with many of the libraries out there currently.

Comment: The code I ended up using is tightly coupled with some other things, but essentially, you need to use requests and rawbody, and when you get a request, make a new request with the rawbody data, then return the request response back to the user.